# How to implement Search API for XML

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, graphql, asp.net-core-webapi, odata

**Scenario:** I'm working on creating *Search API* in .NET6 will search XML data. This XML data exists in the table's specific column named *ExtensionData* only.

Initially, I thought to use [ODATA](https://www.odata.org/) as it seem the best choice for it. But while working discovered that the [EnableQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnet.odata.enablequeryattribute?view=odata-aspnetcore-7.0) works well only with IQueryable as it comes into play before the response is about to be sent to the user. I even thought of using [ODataQueryOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnet.odata.query.odataqueryoptions?view=odata-aspnetcore-7.0) but it also requires a model with fixed properties. Since for *varying XML* I can't have the model, it doesn't seem possible.

Later I thought to use [GraphQL](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet) for the requirement. But the core requirement for it is [schema](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/schema/) which means it also needs a fixed data structure. Hence, I cannot use GraphQL.

**My Efforts:** I have written POC for implementing like this

In *SearchController*, the ActionResult is

```
[EnableQuery]
    [HttpGet("applications/FirstName")]
    [HttpGet("applications/LastName")]
    public IActionResult GetApplications()
    {
        var propertyToGet = new Uri(HttpContext.Request.GetEncodedUrl()).Segments.Last();

        var propertyExist = _extAppService.IsPropertyExist(propertyToGet);
        if (!propertyExist)
            return NotFound();

        var dataTable = _extAppService.SearchProperty(propertyToGet);
        if (dataTable.Rows.Count <= 0)
            return NoContent();

        return Ok(dataTable);
    }
```

And the methods in Service class is like:

```
public DataTable SearchProperty(string propName)
    {
        // TODO: Find way of creating IQueryable and then applying ODATA filter to same

        var rootNodes = _repository.GetRootNodes();
        var searchResults = new DataTable();
        var columnsSet = false;

        foreach (var rootNode in rootNodes)
        {
            var dataTable = SearchPropertyInNode(propName, rootNode);

            if (!columnsSet)
            {
                searchResults = dataTable.Clone();
                columnsSet = true;
            }

            CopyRowsToTable(dataTable, searchResults);
        }

        return searchResults;
    }

    private DataTable SearchPropertyInNode(string propName, string node)
    {
        var sql = $"SELECT X.Y.value('(//{propName})[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS {propName}" +
                  " FROM application a" +
                  $" OUTER APPLY a.ExtensionData.nodes('{node}') as X(Y)"+
                  $" WHERE X.Y.value('(//{propName})[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') <> ''";

        return _repository.ExecuteSql(CommandType.Text, sql);
    }

    private static void CopyRowsToTable(DataTable source, DataTable destination)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < source.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            destination.Rows.Add(source.Rows[i].ItemArray);
        }
    }
```

But this way, I'll require to create a lot of routes for each properties or nodes. To me, it doesn't seem a good way. And still, I can't control more than one property.

**Question:** Now, I'm not sure how else to implement the Search API. Or it might be that I'm not thinking clearly. Do you have any suggestions for me?

Comment: Does your dbms support json columns?

Comment: @Fildor I forgot to mention that the database is in SQL Server. I think it does support JSON columns.

Comment: Have you thought about converting the xml to Json and utilizing the server's json column support?

Comment: Maybe you even could convince whatever source of that data to switch to Json over xml?

Comment: @Fildor Can you please elaborate on how converting XML to JSON can help me in my case?